# Why newer version of a package is not available for previous releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management

Disco is out today, and I just realize this. Of course, releases which are too old lacks some sort of features to support new software, and developers can either implement workarounds or it is simply not possible. However, Cosmic it not really that old at the time of writing, but newest packages are not available for it. There are countless examples:

- `lzip` is available on Cosmic as **1.20-1**, and on Disco as **1.21-3**
- `vlc` is available on Cosmic as **3.0.4-2build1**, and on Disco as **3.0.6-1**
- `gimp` is available on Cosmic as **2.10.6-3**, and on Disco as **2.10.8-2)**
- ...

Is there any technical difficulty, or just because Canonical wants to push people to update their OS?

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: "However, Cosmic it not really that old" yes it is